# How do I get this If statement condition to work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

I'm having a problem with the following piece of code:

```
decision = str(input("Would you like to change it?:"))
if decision.lower == 'yes':
    new_holiday = input("What is your new favorite holiday?:")
```

The problem with this is that when I input 'yes' in the first prompt, instead of showing me the second one as I want, it just skips the if statement completely. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: There's not much more than that to it. Run that and try inputting, or changing the value of 'decision' to yes. The program will end without prompting you for the second time.

Comment: `decision.lower()` ,missing parenthesis

Comment: asking us trust we type exactly the same thing as you do is not a [mre]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decision.lower` generates a method `<built-in method lower of str object at ...>`. you should call  `decision.lower()`.

Change your code to the following:

```
decision = str(input("Would you like to change it?:"))
if decision.lower() == 'yes':
    new_holiday = input("What is your new favorite holiday?:")
```

Comment: Man I'm dumb XD

Answer (score 1):

`decision.lower()` user this method which will return a lower cased string.

```
decision = input("Would you like to change it?:")
if decision.lower() == 'yes':
    new_holiday = input("What is your new favorite holiday?:")
```

Comment: I feel stupid now lol